# Knockout binding not working for the input type="text"

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the following binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericText.defaultPrecision,
                formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

            console.log(formattedValue);
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });
        },
        defaultPrecision: 1
    };
```

and this html

```
      <input id="Price0" data-bind="numericText: price, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
        <input id="Price1" data-bind="numericText: price(), valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
        <input id="Price2" data-bind="value: price, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
        <input id="Price3" data-bind="text: price, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
        1:<span data-bind="text: price"></span>&nbsp;
        2:<span data-bind="text: price()"></span>&nbsp;
```

Now it does work on the spans but not on a input type=text (price0 and price1)

I would like to create a 2-way binding between my viewmodel and a textbox, and this is the first part of my try-process.

When I update the viewmodel the spans are updated, but not the price0 and price1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using the `text` binding inside the `numericText` binding you created. That binding doesn't work on input elements. You need to use the `value` binding instead for those.

EDIT:

I am not sure you can use the value binding in your binding like that. Here is an example of a working value-style binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ValueStyle = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      //update value on vm when box is changed
      $(element).on("change.koBinding", function() {
        var curStr, curVal;
        curVal = valueAccessor();
        curStr = $(element).val();
        curVal(/*put whatever you want the vm to update to here*/);
      });

      //on disposal of binding
      return ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        return $(element).off("change.koBinding");
      });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      // your formatting code here
      return $(element).val(formatted result);
    }
  };
```

Comment: When I change it to `ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });` it doesn't work either....

Comment: Thanks! Formatting the changed data when the vm is updated now succeeds (the `return $(element).val(formatted result);` part) but I can not get the part to work to update the viewmodel. In this part (`curStr = $(element).val();`) I read the new entered value in the input box and the `curVal = valueAccessor()` returns the current vm value. But with this code `curVal(/*put whatever you want the vm to update to here*/);` I can't seem to set the new value in the viewmodel. For instance curVal(7) gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function` and does not set the viewmodel to 7

Comment: I changed the `init` part to this, it seems to work. Does it make sense? `init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            $(element).on("change.koBinding", function() {
                var curStr;
                curStr = $(element).val();
                viewModel.price(Globalize.parseFloat(curStr));
            });
            
            //on disposal of binding
            return ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                return $(element).off("change.koBinding");
            });
        },`

Comment: Yep, that will work fine. The issue you were having sounds like it may be related to your binding value not being observable